# Make Control-C behave like uncaught exception

Tags: c++

Is there a way to make Control-C act like an exception was thrown. i.e. basically the program exits, but on the way up all the destructors are called?

Comment: May be just handle `Ctrl+C` and throw exception on it manually?

Comment: I don't think it's possible. You can register signal handler and from that handler do something destructive with each thread in your application but you can't make them throw exception because this would be identical to code injection.

Comment: Which OS? What type of application? In many a Win32 program, `Ctrl+C` is handles as `Copy to Clipboard`.

Answer (score 1):

Well, you need a signal handler catch SIGINT (SIGTERM, HUP why not as well?). You don't want to use threads for something simple like this, so use the standard "self-pipe trick": write a byte (the signal value) to one end of a socketpair in your signal handler, and your main loop (there's always a select loop in there somewhere) will asynchronously read the value back. It's at that point you throw, run away, follow ordinary quit procedure, do whatever you like. Everything gets unwound and destructed just as if you were quitting for any other reason in your main application loop.

Answer (score 0):

This is generally impossible or hard to do. I believe that on some systems, like GNU/Linux, you could do that if you supplied `-fnon-call-exceptions -fasynchronous-unwind-tables` flags to GCC (untested).

Other than the above, you have basically two options:

1. Either you set some sort of flag in your signal handler that  you will check somewhere else to see if SIGINT has been delivered. This is useful for both *NIX and Windows platforms.
2. On *NIX, if you are using threads in your application already, you can handle SIGINT using, e.g., [sigwait()](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/precise/en/man3/sigwait.3posix.html) in a separate thread as a synchronous event and force your whole application to terminate orderly.

I would suggest using the 2nd option as that is usable as general approach to the problem on Windows as well. Windows inject a thread into application that execute a user supplied handle for Ctrl-C or Ctrl-Break. If you use the 2nd option, your application will be IMHO more portable.